# Successors of perfect squares are not divisible by predecessors of double even numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there a proof for:
successors of perfect squares are not divisible by ( not multiple of ) predecessors of double even numbers, i.e., $n^2+1$ not divisible by $4k-1$, or $3+4k$?

Comment: Well... $-1|2$...

Answer (score 2):

If $n^2+1$ is divisible by a positive integer of the form $4k+3$, then it is divisible by a **prime** $p$ of the form $4k+3$. But it is a standard result of number theory that if $p$ is a prime of that form, then $-1$ is not a quadratic residue of $p$.

For a group-theoretic proof, note that if $n^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$, then $n$ has order $4$. But the order of any group element divides the order of the group, and $4$ does not divide $4k+2$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is relatively straight forward. Combine the following.

1. Any positive integer of the form $4k-1$ has at least one prime factor $p$ of the same form.
2. If $-1$ is a quadratic residue modulo an odd prime $p$, then $p\equiv1\pmod 4$. This is because the square root of $-1$ is an element of order four in $\Bbb{Z}_p^*$, and therefore the order of that group has to be a multiple of four.